# Should I put big amount of data to another table to save performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, entity-relationship

I have a database [ERD connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kKYt.jpg) in MySQL. It's a simple blog application, where the authors can post articles. I would like to know which is the best practise to design my database. I have a post and a post_body table and I separated them, because the post_body may contain lots of data. I use this column only some times, because I use to  list the articles, but the content will be not displayed except the user click the name of the post to visit the full article. So I thought the separation could be good for the performance. Or am I wrong and should I merge these tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With most databases, column location will not be a problem. Sometimes, you can hint data management via data type: e.g. a LARGE TEXT type will in most cases not be text indexed (or it will be indexed only partially) and might actually be stored in a separate file.

The optimization you describe, in other words, is already done by the RDBMS whenever it makes sense, and it is performed in a more efficient and transparent way than you could hope. Except in very special circumstances it's better to leave it alone.

What you really need to do is work on the location of the *rows*. In MySQL you might tackle large tables via partitioning. Before this, however, you need to consider which queries you're running the most, and plan indexing accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations have a high degree of normalization ("more tables") is good, and clean. The multi-table database is a lot more flexible if any of these one to one relationships may become one to many or many to many in the future. For example, if you need to store multiple addresses for some customers, it's a lot easier if you have a customer table and an address table.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this a few times.  Here are some things to consider.

- Are you often scanning the 'meta' data (columns other than the 'body'), and don't need the 'body'?
- Are you unable to adequately `INDEX` the table, such that you have to fetch and check extra meta columns before deciding on which row(s) you need?

Both of those lead to "Am I stumbling over bulky bodies that I don't need?"  If yes, then "vertical partitioning" *may* be desirable for performance.

If you are early in your deployment of the product, I recommend "KISS"; this is, don't bother with the complexity of vertical partition until you determine that it is needed.

Another consideration is

- Is the 'body' (or whatever it is) "optional"?  That is, do many of your rows not have a value for that column(s)?  (This will lead to doing `LEFT JOIN` when fetching the 'body'.)

If you decide to do it...

```
CREATE TABLE main (
    id ... PRIMARY KEY  -- perhaps AUTO_INCREMENT
)
CREATE TABLE bulky_stuff(
    id ... PRIMARY KEY  -- not AUTO_INCREMENT, but value matches `main.id`
    body MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL ...
)
```

In MyISAM (which you should not be using), vertical partitioning is often useful; in InnoDB, it is less often useful because of how that engine usually puts bulky columns in separate blocks.  Changing the `ROW_FORMAT`, perhaps to `DYNAMIC`, may be a better (that is, 'simpler') solution.